# Cannot Achieve Unsafe Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I was revising MultiThreading using Java. As I remember if you dont make a method Synchronized(on object or instance) then, the Method can be parallely executed by multiple threads. And this is what happens generally.
Below is the code i wrote

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;


class FileIn
{
    File f;
    BufferedWriter br;

    public FileIn(String path) throws IOException
    {
        f = new File(path);
        br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
    }

    public void write(String a) throws IOException
    {
        br.write(a);
        br.newLine();
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        br.close();
    }
}

class ThreadWriter extends Thread
{
    private FileIn f;
    private String tname;
    public ThreadWriter(FileIn f,String name)
    {
        this.f=f;
        this.tname=name;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{
            for(int i =1;i<=20;i++)
            {
                f.write("This is Line "+i+" of "+tname);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Three
{

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        FileIn f;
        Thread[] t = new Thread[4];
        try{
            f = new FileIn("F:/files.txt");
            t[0]=new ThreadWriter(f,"Thread 1");
            t[1]=new ThreadWriter(f,"Thread 2");
            t[2]=new ThreadWriter(f,"Thread 3");
            t[3]=new ThreadWriter(f,"Thread 4");
            t[0].run();
            t[1].run();
            t[2].run();
            t[3].run();
            f.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The output is very ordered, without any difference in different runs. And its like the same if i would have written in sequentially in main.

```
This is Line 1 of Thread 1
This is Line 2 of Thread 1
This is Line 3 of Thread 1
This is Line 4 of Thread 1
This is Line 5 of Thread 1
This is Line 1 of Thread 2
This is Line 2 of Thread 2
This is Line 3 of Thread 2
This is Line 4 of Thread 2
This is Line 5 of Thread 2
This is Line 1 of Thread 3
This is Line 2 of Thread 3
This is Line 3 of Thread 3
This is Line 4 of Thread 3
This is Line 5 of Thread 3
This is Line 1 of Thread 4
This is Line 2 of Thread 4
This is Line 3 of Thread 4
This is Line 4 of Thread 4
This is Line 5 of Thread 4
```

I thought it can occur due to something CPU specific but the program here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm
Runs as it is supposed to - Threads Overlapping each other without being Synchronized.

I thought that BufferedWriter may be already ThreadSafe, which may allow it to do something like this.(even though the thread wont hold lock on BufferdWriter, FileIn should) , but apparently it is not.

So Why is this not acting like an Thread Unsafe Method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not starting any new threads, but executing the `Thread` object's run method on the original main thread. You need to call `thread.start()` not `thread.run()`.

If you do fix this, you may still get the same output if your task for each thread is rather short. Make sure the work to do is long enough to see the behavior you want.

Comment: I knew that, but somehow even after looking at the code and checking other codes, i missed that. I even wrote earlier programs today where i used the start method.
I feel so stupid :(

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri It's all good, it's a very easy brain fart type mistake to make even for a seasoned developer.